# How to use the TikZ(LaTex) tool for the drupal 7 site?

Tags: plugins, drupal-7, ckeditor, drupal-modules

I have been trying to get answer from the Drupal answer, but although being too specif I am not getting answer as my question put on Hold, probably it will take some time to get removed from hold position as I have re-formatted few our ago. Like MathJax(LaTex), which we can use in drupal site for writing mathematical formulas either through installing its module or providing plugin to CKEditor. I came to know that **TikZ(Latex) is use for displaying the mathematical diagrams i.e. X-Y co-ordinate, Circle, Triangle, various graphs..etc.** So, is there any module or plugin which allow TikZ to work on drupla 7 site. I am providing here the [Drupal answer link for complete explanation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192557/how-to-use-tikzlatex-in-drupal-7-site). Truly appreciating any help, Thanks

Comment: The heart of this problem is that while there's libraries to convert maths formulae to HTML (and web-fonts to support this), there doesn't seem to be an equivalent package to e.g. convert TikZ images to SVG (or something similar). Your best bet is probably to find something that accepts TikZ code and renders an image you can display (but that's probably not what you're asking here).

Comment: Yes, MathJax takes its code and display in the form of equation for that MathJax module is there.  Same way I am looking for TikZ, some module/plugin or way, so it takes TikZ code and display as image/whatever form it uses.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/929014 seems to answer a similar question

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for the link, I will try to dig there, looks there is a some way to do this by coding, also I will put comment there if needed...